# colorscale = "Rainbow" in plot_ly doesn't work

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I am trying to plot a 3d surface by using plot_ly package.

```
x = c(1:10)
y = c(1:10)
z = matrix(runif(100),ncol = 10)
z_col = matrix(runif(100),ncol = 10)

plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, surfacecolor =~ z_col, 
        type = "surface", colorscale = "Rainbow")
```

I expect the the color for the color bar will be like this:
[image]

However, this is what I get:
[image]

Can anyone show me how to show this problem ?

Comment: *Surfaces* plot type does **not accept palete name strings** like scatter plots for example. You can comprove it trying to set any other palete name string like `Greys, Portland, Jet, Hot, Blackbody, Earth, Electric, etc`. Notice that nothing will happen with the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#surface-colorscale):

> colorscale (colorscale)
>   Sets the colorscale. The colorscale must be
>   an array containing arrays mapping a normalized value to an rgb, rgba,
>   hex, hsl, hsv, or named color string. At minimum, a mapping for the
>   lowest (0) and highest (1) values are required. 
>   For example, `[[0, 'rgb(0,0,255)', [1, 'rgb(255,0,0)']]`.

You can define your own rainbow colorscale by using

```
colorscale = cbind(seq(0, 1, by=1/(length(z) - 1)), rainbow(length(z)))
```

which gives you

[image]