# R plotly: bar plot with rainbow like gradient color across bars

Tags: r, colors, plotly, bar-chart

I would like to create a plot like below using `plotly`

[image: plot example]

Specifically I would like the color scale goes from green to read with gradient change. I also want a side color bar indicating the value range. The values of the `x` axis range from `0` to `1`. Bars for smaller values are closed to green. Bars with lager values gradually change to red.

Below is my current code

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)

# create data for testing
make_test_data <- function(n_row) tibble(ID = stringr::str_pad(seq(n_row), 6, pad = '0'),
                                                 parameter = stats::runif(n_row))
df_test <- make_test_data(30)

# draw bar plot with plot_ly
plot_ly(df_test, x = ~parameter, y = ~ID, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Parameter Name (Unit)', range = c(0, 1), tickvals = seq(0, 1, 0.2)), 
         yaxis = list(title = 'Sample ID', categoryorder = "total ascending"))
```

This just give me bar plot with a single default color. I then tried the following according to the [answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46894416/2883282).

```
plot_ly(df_test, x = ~parameter, y = ~ID, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
        colorscale = cbind(seq(0, 1, by=1/(length(~ID) - 1)), rainbow(length(~ID)))) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Parameter Name (Unit)', range = c(0, 1), tickvals = seq(0, 1, 0.2)), 
         yaxis = list(title = 'Sample ID', categoryorder = "total ascending"))
```

But I got the warning below and the same single color bars. Seems bar type does not support `colorscale`. Is there any workaround? I need a solution using solely `plot_ly`, **not** `ggplotly + ggplot`.

```
Warning message:
'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'colorscale'
Valid attributes include:
'_deprecated', 'alignmentgroup', 'base', 'basesrc', 'cliponaxis', 'constraintext', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextanchor', 'insidetextfont', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'offset', 'offsetgroup', 'offsetsrc', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'outsidetextfont', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'text', 'textangle', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'width', 'widthsrc', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiod [... truncated]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign the color to a variable. Additionally, if you're using `colorscale`, I'm pretty sure it needs to be nested in `marker`.

This code has a lot of callouts for the `colorbar`, so that it closely resembles the plot you are trying to emulate. Additionally, I used `set.seed()` so I would be able to have repeatable results.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)

# create data for testing
set.seed(539)
make_test_data <- function(n_row) tibble(ID = stringr::str_pad(seq(n_row), 6, pad = '0'),
                                         parameter = stats::runif(n_row))
df_test <- make_test_data(30)

# draw bar plot with plot_ly
plot_ly(df_test, x = ~parameter, y = ~ID, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
        marker = list(colorscale = list(c(0,1), c("lawngreen", "red")),
                      colorbar = list(title = "Parameter Name (Unit)",
                                      len = .4, outlinewidth = 0,
                                      tickformat = ".2f",
                                      tick0 = 0, dtick = .25),
                      color = ~parameter)) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Parameter Name (Unit)', 
                      range = c(0, 1), tickvals = seq(0, 1, 0.2)), 
         yaxis = list(title = 'Sample ID', categoryorder = "total ascending"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks. Is there way to adjust how the gradient changes from green to red? It seems your plot has a lot of colors in red very closely. The color actually indicates kind of severity of the sample, thus I like to separate them a big better particularly for the red zone.

Comment: The bars that are close together in color are close together in value. For example, if you change the seed to 39 and rerun the code, you'll see the bar values are more spread out and therefore the colors are, as well.